# Maxlength in Wix Edit control

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is there a way to specify the maximum number of characters allowed in an edit control in Wix?There does not appear to be a property such as Maxlength.

The only option I can think of is to use a [MaskedEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369797(VS.85).aspx) control, but there is no option to specify the field length directly. So, to set the Maxlength to say 50 characters, I would have to type 50 wild card characters in the mask. I was hoping for an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Edit Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368342%28VS.85%29.aspx) documentation:

> The length of text that can be entered
>   can be limited by putting a number
>   from 0 to 2147483646 in curly braces
>   at the beginning of the Text field in
>   the Control table. For example, if the
>   text field starts with {80}, the
>   length of the string is limited at 80
>   characters. If no such limit is
>   supplied in the table, or if 0 is
>   specified, the length is set to the
>   maximum possible (2147483646
>   characters). A negative or non-numeric
>   value will generate an error.

Comment: Thanks! 
Note to self: Should not rely solely on Wix documentation, and must always consult the underlying MSI documentation.

Comment: So, how to do that using Wix XML ? That is just specifying that how to put it in control table, but that is something that WiX does it by itself...

Comment: @NaveedButt do this: `<Control Id="Mycontrol" Type="Edit" Text="{8192}"/>`

Comment: When using properties this works just the same to restrict the value to 50 characters: `<Control Id="YourEdit" Type="Edit" X="86" Y="65" Width="321" Height="15" Property="YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME">   <Text>{50}[YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME]</Text>   </Control>`